# Need to fetch all the records of table "#Tbl1" which "DisplayId" not present in table "#Tbl2"

Tags: sql-server-2008

I need to Need to fetch all the records of table "#Tbl1" which "DisplayId" not present in table "#Tbl2".

1. "#Tbl1" having Max 100 records
2. "#Tbl2" is growing table

   Create Table #Tbl1(Id1 Int Identity(1,1), DisplayId Nvarchar(200), Name Nvarchar(200))
   Insert Into #Tbl1(DisplayId, Name) Values ('d1', 'ABC'),('d2', 'PQR')

   Create Table #Tbl2(Id2 Int Identity(1,1), DisplayId Nvarchar(200))
   Insert Into #Tbl2(DisplayId) Values ('d1')

Below query is working, but looking for efficient query and please suggest what kind of Index is required to which table's column?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2

```
Select * From #Tbl1
Where DisplayId Not In (Select DisplayId From #Tbl2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the in statement does seem to be slow generally, I would use an exists statement if possible but I'm not sure if it is supported on SQL Server 2008. Other option you have is a left join which will also be slow.

An exists or (not exists) statement works like this

```
select * from #tbl1 t1 
where not exists (select displayid from #tbl2 where displayid = t1.displayid)
```

Notice the use of the alias t1, you do not have to select a column in the sub select, you can use a wildcard *.  I've found this type of query is far more efficient because it uses the index links directly between the 2 tables instead of first selecting all the columns and then filtering them.

Comment: do we need any non-cluster index

Comment: I would create and test with both, if you look at the execution plan for the query you should be able to see which one the optimizer will choose, some feedback would be great, I have never played much with the type of index to see if it provides further speed improvements.